# Mass Effect Missions counters bugged

Tags: bug, status-completed, contests, me3missions

Looks like the counters for the ME3 missions got bugged. I used to have 11 5+ scoring posts in the mission, now it shows me with 8. You can see the bugged numbers in [my profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11920/ben-brocka). As you can see from this search, [I actually have 11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:11920%20votes:5%20%5Bmass-effect-3%5D&submit=search).

From what I heard in chat, this happened to everyone. Probably a counter bug.

And now the problem is happening intermittantly; every other refresh the counter is correct/incorrect. Weirdness.

Comment: Another example with [my own query](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12823+votes%3A1+%5Bmass-effect-3%5D&submit=search) and image of my profile for reference: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy3SI.png)

Comment: Mine went from 20/25 (which is correct) to 14/25 last night to 19/25 this morning. It's all over the place.

Comment: mine looks consistent now. IS anyone still having this problem?

Comment: Was broken momentarily (for the first time) for me just a minute ago, might be a particular server out of sync or something...

Comment: I checked 10 minutes ago and it said 23/25. Now it says 15/25. Still broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be resolved now. Our handling of API results was way too sensitive to certain effects caused by our public API not supporting cursoring (yes, we're using the public API wherever we can).

These effects always fixed themselves within 5 to 10 minutes, but the fluctuation in the numbers is of course annoying. It shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: +1 for eating your own dogfood